# Why is there unneeded geometry poking out when using the bevel modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

I really haven't done much with the shape other than using a boolean mod and cutting a rounded rectangle out of this larger prism. I wanted to curve everything but to make it look less sharp so I decided on using the bevel modifier. However, when doing so, there are these crazy things that are poking out of the inside of this shape. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image: first view of issue]
[image: second view of issue]

Comment: maybe you shouldn't delete your boolean object and provide your blend file so we can see what you did.

Comment: @Chris How would I provide my blend file? (I've also kept my boolean object, but I've unfortunately already applied the mod)

Comment: Open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: @Chris here is the Blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=ew3wRvEa" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/ew3wRvEa/)

Comment: Please don't post your files in the comments, edit them into your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that your circle object has wrong face orientation. By that everything else does fail.

So select your circle, got to edit mode, press A, mesh -> normals -> recalculate outside and try again.

result:

[image]